# Dash App (An object was provided as `children` instead of a component)

Tags: plotly-dash

I was supposed to build the functionality of a file section. For example, if some clicks the row he/she should be able to see the relevant files. I am getting A**n object was provided as `children` instead of a component** error. Can someone tell me what should i do. I have attached pictures of the project. We are using Dash.plotly as a framework. Here is my code :

```
FILE_QUERY = "SELECT public.relevant_sources.id AS id, link From public.relevant_sources"

def get_file_list(self):
        files=[]
        data = result=self.connection.execute(FILE_QUERY)
        for file in data:
            jobdict=dict(file)
            files.append(jobdict)
            print(files)
        return files
```

Above code is in database_helper.py class

In my juiceboard.py file this is what i have written :

```
    # Right column
        html.Div(
            id='right-column',
            className='column',
            children=[
                html.Div(id='main-plot',children=[]),
                html.Div(id='right-menu',children=[DEFAULT_RIGHT_MENU]),
                html.Div(id='file-div',
                    children=[
                        html.H2('Files'),
                        html.Div(id='file-list',children=[]),

                    ],
                ),
            ],
        ),

@app.callback(
    [
        Output('data-table','style_data_conditional'),
        Output('main-plot','children'),
        Output('right-menu','children'),
        Output('file-list', 'children'),
    ],
```

I am not able to see out. [image: I have attached a picture of the error.]
In my data base the name of the table is relevant_source. From this table i just need to display links. Right it has 2 columns one is id and the second one is links. The data in links is like this " https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D56324, https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D56612 "